# abline() in R - years on the x-axis

Tags: r

I know probably that is a quite simple question, but I have tried several times.
Could someone explain how I can draw a line in a plot that starts 3, 1920 and ends at 1, 2021?

Here my example code:

```
 a= c(3, 2, 1)
 b= c(1920,1940,1980)
 plot(b, a)
 abline(a=3, b=-1)
```

Comment: `plot(b, a, xlim = c(1920, 2021)); lines(c(1920, 2021), c(3, 1))`

Comment: Do you mean `plot(b, a, type = "l")`?